# How to get character index onClick [HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, indexing, character

it's possible to know the character index onClick, relative to the HTML body.

I tried to search, without success.
I can't use Jquery, because i'm using Angular JS / Ionic

Comment: What is a character index?

Comment: Why would you like to use index when you can pass the value as a function parameter?

Comment: Can you include some example html or something to make it clearer what you're wanting?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to know which character among a string of characters was clicked, you would have to attach an event listener to each of them. In your template:

```
<span ng-click="charClick(0)">H<span>
<span ng-click="charClick(1)">E<span>
<span ng-click="charClick(2)">L<span>
<span ng-click="charClick(3)">L<span>
<span ng-click="charClick(4)">O<span>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.charClick = function (index) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

This is quite nasty. You should probably use a `ng-repeat` to render each character so that you don't have to manually repeat that much code.